# installed Software Version

Tags: windows, c#, vb.net, auto-updates

I am developing software which is distributed through setup (Create with old Visual Studio 2003) and which is AutoUpdated through an AutoUpdate I created.

This AutoUpdate replaces new files, updates the database, etc... What I don't know HOW to do is UPDATING the software VERSION which can be seen in Windows - Panel Controls -> Installed applications.

After the update my software main .exe shows the correct version in Properties. In this image example I installed the 3.3.0 version, then update to 3.3.7:

[image]

How can I update that 'label' version which can be seen in Installed applications?

I prefer a vb.net solution but I could use a C# solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically not doing things properly and you want to do a wrong thing.
In .NET you can use ClickOnce, that can do this for you, using MSI package you can create a new update MSI package to upgrade existing installation
[see here how](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22256/NewSetupVersion-for-MSI-Projects). That would be a standard and correct approaach.

However if you just need to **hack** the version displayed in control panel, you can edit your app entry under following registry hive:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

There you just edit the `DisplayVersion` string value to whatever you want for whatever reason. But if your installed MSI is just a bootstrapper, I do not see any reason to hack its displayed version number.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Vojtěch Dohnal, this is EXACTLY what i was looking for.